# $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ subspace has two connected components where $C$ is a circle.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let's look at $\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual metric topology and in it circle. Then author says that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ subspace has two connected components.

First of all I need to check they are connected components. They are not subset of each other so we need to check if they are connected subsets. In order to prove they are connected subsets we must show that they can't be written union of two non-empty disjoint open sets. Here is where I stuck. I don't know how to show they can't be written like that.

EDIT.

I read and can understand first part of proof of @MoisheKohan , but I am stuck on second part.We know that $Lp∪Lq$ is connected how conclude that A is connected as well?

Comment: I would show path-connectedness, perhaps using polar coordinates. Then use the fact that path-connectedness is stronger than connectedness.

Comment: @TheoBendit We haven't studied path-connectedness. But we studied what are open sets in usual metric topology.Maybe there is easier way showing   that then can't be written union of two open sets?

Comment: I still think the path-connectedness option would be easiest, even if it means you having to prove that path-connectedness implies connectedness. What do you know about connectedness? What sets do you know are connected, and what techniques were used to prove this? Do you know any results that provide sufficient conditions for connectedness?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes we proved that $R^2/(x_0,y_0)$ is connected

Comment: Proved that $[a,b]$ is is connected in ($R$,usual metric topology)

Comment: Well, you could show that the map$$\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\} \to \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus B[0; 1] : x \mapsto x + \frac{x}{\|x\|}$$is continuous and surjective, and that the continuous image of connected sets are connected. If you know that $\Bbb{R}^2$ is connected, you could also consider the map$$\Bbb{R}^2 \to B(0; 1) : x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\| + 1}$$to show that $B(0; 1)$ is connected too.

Comment: Sorry for silly question but can you please explain what you mean by $x \mapsto x + \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ in domain we have $x\in R^2$ yes?

Comment: I mean the map that takes any point $x \in \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, and produces the point $x + \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. If we map $x = (a, b)$, then this comes to $(a, b) + \frac{(a, b)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$. Note that we can map any $x \in \Bbb{R}^2$ so long as $x \neq 0$. We cannot divide by $\|x\|$ when it is $0$, which is precisely when $x = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Do you already know that each interval is connected? Do you know that the union of two intersecting connected subsets is also connected?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I know that.

Comment: Two of @TheoBendit's suggestions in separate comments can be combined: use polar coordinates, and the theorem that a continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Answer (score 3):

Since this problem is likely used as a homework, I will only leave a sequence of hints:

1. First of all, you have to figure out what "they" are in the sentence "First of all I need to check they are connected components." Let's call "them"  simply $A$ and $B$. Once you identify "them," you will have no trouble checking that ${\mathbb R}^2 \setminus C$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, and that both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty.
2. Next, you will prove that one of these subsets, namely $B$, is *convex*, which means that with every pair of points $p, q\in B$, the line segment $pq$ is also contained in $B$. Now, use the fact that you already know, namely that the (straight) line segments $pq$ are connected, to show that $B$ cannot be written as a disjoint union of two nonempty open subsets. (You will be arguing by contradiction.)
3. Then, you proceed to analyze $A$. This subset is not convex. But you will prove that it has the following property:

For every pair of points $p, q\in A$, there are line segments $L_p, L_q$ both contained in $A$ and containing $p, q$ respectively, such that $L_p\cap L_q\ne \emptyset$.

The proof of existence of such line segments can be done in many ways, for instance, using axiomatic Euclidean geometry, or trigonometry, or analytic geometry, or linear algebra.

Afterwards, you argue that $L_p\cup L_q$ is connected. (In a comment you indicated that you already know how to prove that if $Y, Z$ are connected subsets of a topological space and $Y\cap Z$ is nonempty, then $Y\cup Z$ is connected.) Lastly, arguing as in Part 2, you conclude that $A$ is connected as well.

This will conclude the proof.

Comment: I haven't studied convex sets in my class, what I need to know about them to use your hints?

Comment: @unit1991: All you need to know is the definition of convexity that I gave and knowledge of elementary geometry (lines and circles in the plane). I assume you did study elementary geometry in high school or, at least, linear algebra and vector calculus in college, right?

Comment: @Yes I studied.

Comment: Thank you.I will try to use your hints and make future edits if questions arise

Comment: I did some work and have  questions.Can you please elaborate more about how to prove existence of such line segments? And then let's say we know that $B$ is convex I can't understand from having  that $pq$ is connected how that can help to show that $B$ is connected.

Comment: @unit1991 Sorry, but what I wrote is as much as I can say.

Comment: I understand proof of first part.Can you only help me with the part when I already have that $L_p \cup L_q$ is connected how from this conclude that $A$  is also connected?

Answer (score 1):

Let us choose the circle $C_r =\{(x,y):x^2 +y^2=r^2\}$

Claim: $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ has two connected components , one is bounded and other is unbounded.

$ B(0, r) =\{(x,y):x^2 +y^2<r^2\}$

\begin{align}Ext[B(0, r)]&=\{(x,y):x^2 +y^2>r^2\}\end{align}

$\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r=B(0, 1) \sqcup Ext[B(0, r) ]$

> Connected component: $(X, \tau) $ be a topological space.Let, $p\in
>  X$, then connected component of $X$ containing $p$ is the maximal
> connected subsets of $X$ containing $p$.

Let, $p\in \Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ , then either $p \in B(0, r) $ or $p\in Ext[B(0, r) ]$

Case I: $p \in B(0, r) $

Clearly, $ B(0, r) $ is a connected subset of $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ containing $p$.

And it is again easy to see it is the maximal connected subset of $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ containing $p$.

If $\exists M\subset \Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ properly containing $B(0, r) $, then $M$ contain points $q_i$  of $Ext[B(0, r) ]$.

As $Ext[B(0, r) ]$ is open subsets of $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$, there exists an open set $U_i$ containing $q_i$.

Then , $U=\cup_{i}U_i\subset \Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ is open .

and

$M=B(0, r) \sqcup U\implies M$ is not connected.

Hence, $B(0, r) $ is a connected component of $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ for any point inside it.

Case II: Using similar argument you can prove easily, for any $p\in Ext[B(0, r) ]$ maximal connected subset containing $p$ is the $Ext[B(0, r) ]$.

Combining above two cases, we can say $\Bbb{R^2}\setminus C_r$ has two connected components $B(0, r) $ and $Ext[B(0, r) ]$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more why B(0,r)  and Ext[B(0,r)] are connected?

Comment: That is one of the main part in the problem that I have hard time proving.

Comment: @unit 1991 Any two point in $B(0, r) $ can be joined by a continuous map.For any two points $x, y\in B(0, r) $ , $f:[0, 1]\to X$ defined by $f(t) =(1-t) x+ty$. And any path connected set is connected.

Comment: In my question it is mentioned that I want to solve without path connectdness. Is there other way proving that this two subsets are connected?Like using open sets in metric topology.

Comment: @unit 1991 Path connectedness is an easiest way to prove connectedness. I don't know why you are bothering about path connectedness. But otherwise you can prove intervals in  $\Bbb{R}$ is connected and all norms on $\Bbb{R^2}$ are equivalent and open rectangle $(0, 1) ×(0, 1) $  is connected in $\Bbb{R^{2}}$ (As product of two connected subsets)

Comment: Why if $(0,1)×(0,1)$  is connected follows that open ball  is connected?

Comment: @unit $(0, 1) ×(0, 1) $ is homeomorhic to $ D(0, 1) $

Comment: Isn't that circular argument?You are using $D(0,1)$ is connected to prove that $B(0,1)$ is connected?

Comment: @unit 1991 $B(0, 1) $ in euclidean topology of $\Bbb{R^2}$ is exactly $D(0, 1) $

Comment: @unit 1991 it will be lot easier if you know path connectedness i.e any two points can be joined by a continuous path.

Comment: @SourabGhosh I read about it and can understand first part of proof of MoisheKohan, can you help understand second part?We know that $L_p \cup L_q $ is connected how conclude that $A$ is connected as well?

Comment: See here https://www.google.com/amp/s/mathstrek.blog/2013/03/07/topology-path-connected-spaces/amp/